# BezierSegment Length

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

How can I calculate BezierSegment Length?

currently I am calculating the length between its 3 points, this is of course not exact. Is it a better way to get it?

```
//p1, p2 and p3 are points.
var bs = new BezierSegment(p1, p2, p3, true);
var l = 0d;
l += Math.Sqrt(
                Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), 2) +
                Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y), 2));
l += Math.Sqrt(
                Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p2.X - p3.X), 2) +
                Math.Pow(Math.Abs(p2.Y - p3.Y), 2));
```

Comment: I don't know if there's a standard method for this, but the answer is given here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/arc-length-of-b%c3%a9zier-curves

Comment: @PaulBoddington are you sure thats the method BezierSegment uses?

Comment: I don't know anything about `BezierSegment` I'm afraid. All I know is that's the length of a quadratic Bezier curve.